# Rails - Find records that are not present another join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to write a ActiveRecord statment where I'm looking for all records where the id isn't present in another table...

Whats the syntax?

```
 @events =  Event.find(:all, :include => :personals, 
                  :conditions => ["event.id != ? ", @user.personal.event_id ])
```

Where personals is a join table that has the user_id and a event_id....

SO i'm essentially trying to find every event record that the user hasn't added to their own set of personal records....

Is there a better way to write this.... not null or something?

Comment: Are you getting a specific error, or just curious if that's the most efficient way?

Comment: A better answer can be provided if how are the relationships set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume the relationships are as follows:

```
User: 
has_many :personals
has_many :events, :through => :personals

Event:
has_many :personals
has_many :users, :through => :personals

Personal:
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user
```

My solution would be to use the auto-created association function for User "event_ids" that lists all of the event ids in User.events. The query to get what you're trying to do should be:

```
Event.find(:all, :include => :personals, :conditions => ["events.id NOT IN (?)", @user.event_ids])
```

And, unless you actually need the join, you can simplify:

```
Event.find(:all, :conditions => ["events.id NOT IN (?)", @user.event_ids])
```

The key is the SQL command, "NOT IN (x)". Also, note the "events.id" is plural for the model name, according to SQL convention.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Won't this generate two SQL commands - one that collects ? `@user.event_ids`, and one that does `NOT IN [all those ids]` .. which is fine for many cases, but if there are hundreds of thousands `@user.event_ids`, then something that generates pure SQL is preferred; right?

Answer (score 16):

The other answers don't scale well with hundreds of thousands or more records. Here's a pure SQL solution.

Rails 5+:

```
Event.left_outer_joins(:personals).where(personals: {event_id: nil})
```

This retrieves all Events that do not have an associated Personal.

Rails 3+:

```
Event.joins('LEFT JOIN personals ON event.id = personals.event_id').where('personals.event_id IS NULL')
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct. I understood he wanted to get entries if they do no contain a certain id. This will also skip those which have just different id (the id must be somehow in the query)

Comment: Thanks--you are right, I misread the question. This answers "given Event has many Personals, how do I get all Events who do not have any Personals". I now see the question is "given Event has many Personals, and User has many Personals, how do I get all Events which don't share any Personals with some User u".

Answer (score 9):

The solution presented by Nuby is as correct as ever. Here's the same query in a modern syntax, which can be used in Rails 3 and higher:

```
Event.where.not(id: @user.event_ids)
```

Comment: This will generate a massive (almost certainly illegal) select statement where the ids are just included in the text.  You really need something that does a join.

Comment: @JamesMoore `Event.where.not(id: @user.events.select(:id))`

Answer (score 0):

Best I've got so far:

```
events = Event.left_joins(:personals)
events.where.not(personals: { event_id: @user.personal.event_id }).or(
  events.where(personals: { event_id: nil })
)
```

Produces SQL:

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "personals" 
ON "personals"."event_id" = "events"."id" 
WHERE ("personals"."event_id" != $1 OR "personals"."event_id" IS NULL)
```