# How to simulate a NOT IN SQL condition in the following case

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 and I would like to get all the `@products` that haven't been already added to the `listed_products` array.

For example, let's say I've got the following code:

```
listed_products = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

#Then, I would like to do something like SELECT * FROM products where id not in
#(listed_products), and save the result in @products
```

I know the above SQL syntax won't work, but I just wanted to give you guys the idea of what I want to achieve.

Is there a "rails way" for doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818466/rails-find-records-that-are-not-present-another-join-table/4818822#4818822

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do the following (Rails 2.3.x):

```
listed_products = [1,2,3,4,5]
Product.find(:all, :conditions => ["id NOT IN (?)", listed_products])
```

Or this in Rails 3.0.x:

```
listed_products = [1,2,3,4,5]
Product.where("id NOT IN (?)", listed_products)
```

Comment: You can still use scopes in Rails 2.3.x:

Comment: Of course you can, but the scopes take a different format (scope vrs named_scope), and the where function doesn't exist. That's why there are two different functions here. Either way, I'm not using user-defined scopes in this example.

Comment: My point was that the two methods you list, where() and find(), are, in fact, different - the where() method returns a scope, the find method does not, when you can, in fact, do the same thing as where() in 2.3.x.  A very minor nit...

Comment: Be careful, this will not work when the array is empty. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307411/how-to-express-a-not-in-query-with-activerecord-rails#comment16110205_6817170

Answer (score 1):

Pan's answer is correct, but you can also use scopes in 2.3.8, which lets you chain with other scopes for the class:

```
class Product
    ...
    named_scope :excluding_ids, lambda { |*ids|
      if ids.count==0 then
        {}
      else
        {:conditions => ["id NOT IN (?)",ids]}
      end
    }
    ...
end
```

Then you can chain with other scopes in your class.  Say you have a scope named :active.  Then you can do:

```
Products.active.excluding_ids(*listed_products).find :all, ... more conditions ...
```

and it would be independent of order of the scopes:

```
Products.excluding_ids(*listed_products).active.find :all, ..
```

Answer (score -1):

The best I can think of is:

```
SELECT * FROM products where id not = '1' and id not = '2' (etc...)
```

Not what you're after I'm sure, but it may be the only way!